# NestJs - Property added in service is not returned

Tags: typescript, api, nestjs

I'm using NestJs connected with mongoDb. The objects in mongo (and the scheme in nestjs) has the following structure `{NAME: string, YEAR: number, COVER: string}`.

The interface and dto has the structure

```
export class NAME {
    readonly NAME: string;
    readonly YEAR: number;
    readonly COVER: string;
    COVER_BASE64: string;
}

export interface NAME extends Document {
    readonly NAME: string;
    readonly YEAR: number;
    readonly COVER: string;
    COVER_BASE64: string;
}
```

In service class I've the next function that appends to objects getting from Mongo the cover_base64 property.

```
async getAlbums(): Promise<Album[]> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.model.find().exec((err, objs) => {
                if (err) { reject(err); }
                const objres = objs.map(obj => {
                    const base64 = this.getBase64(obj);
                    obj.COVER_BASE64 = base64;
                    return obj;
                });
                resolve(objsres);
            });
        });
   }
```

The problem is the objects returned in controller class has not the COVER_BASE64 property. But debugging the service, I see that each 'albumsRes' object has the property COVER_BASE64 with the correct value but debugging controller the property seems to be 'disappear'.

There is a reason for that property has not to be present in controller and in, for example postman, the http request does not get COVER_BASE64 property.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it because of absence of `await` for new promise?. It also explains why in debug mode it works correctly.
Try:

```
async getAlbums(): Promise<Album[]> {
        return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.model.find().exec((err, objs) => {
                if (err) { reject(err); }
                const objres = objs.map(obj => {
                    const base64 = this.getBase64(obj);
                    obj.COVER_BASE64 = base64;
                    return obj;
                });
                resolve(objsres);
            });
        });
   }
```

Comment: It seems that is not working with the await. I've noticed that if I overwrite the COVER property is returning in http response. Can only working with the mongoDb object properties?